# Algolia relationship one to many

Tags: indexing, one-to-many, algolia

i’ve a dilemma and require your technical help. I want to store 2 tables in Algolia.

- One table that contains offers for an office.
- One table that contains every bookings for those offers.
  In my MySQL DB, there is a One-To-Many relationship, but since i’m new to document database, i don’t know how to handle relations in Algolia.

The way i see it , i have two options:

- i replicate my schema : 2 indices, and i need to make 2 search queries each time.
- i have one index for which each record contains a booking with the offer data ( the data of the offer is, then, duplicated )

What seems to be a good choice ? in matter of good practice and pricing ?

Answer (score 1):

Glad we were able to answer you directly.  Re-posting the gist of the response here:

Here's how you could format your data:

```
[{
  objectID: '120',
  officeName: 'Super office',
  availabilityStart: timestampLastIndexing,
  availabilityEnd: timestampOneYearInTheFutureFromLastIndexing
}]
```

This would be the state when you start your index, without any booking, it means there would be one record per office and availabilityStart would be the time of last indexing, availabilityEnd would be one year in the future.

Then if someone makes a booking for July 12 for this office (120, Super Office), you would have to update your index this way:

```
[{
  objectID: '120',
  officeName: 'Super office',
  availabilityStart: timestampLastIndexing,
  availabilityEnd: timestampJuly11EndOfTheDay
}, {
  objectID: '120',
  officeName: 'Super office',
  availabilityStart: timestampJuly13StartOfTheDay,
  availabilityEnd: timestampOneYearInTheFutureFromJuly13StartOfTheDay
}]
```

Basically you have to update your index everytime a booking is made and merge adjacent days while also making sure that someone in the process of booking does not have a bad surprise when the booking is completed if someone completed it before (classic booking design issue).

On your frontend, you would have to make requests this way:

```
index.search({
  query: ..,
  filters: 'userSelectedTimestamp >= availabilityStart AND userSelectedTimestamp <= availabilityEnd'
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, i know booking problems are hard to solve but this seems to be the best way to store availabilities. All the logic must be while indexing but querying is easy, so we will give it a try